# Upgrade path for Jaunty Server?

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, 9.10, 9.04

I have a very old installation of Jaunty that I would like to eventually get up to the current version of Ubuntu LTS.

I cannot do the normal network upgrades, as there is no continued support for this.  My question is, can I mount a .iso file for Ubuntu 10.04 and upgrade to that from this mounted CD?

I understand that it would be better to do a fresh install at this point, but that may be difficult, as I don't have direct physical access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was ble with a small tweak to upgrade "as-usual" my Jaunty server and Desktop installations to the latest LTS.

I have put all the details [how to do a smooth upgrade from Jaunty to Karmic (even if EOL) in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/135028/3004).